# QGis export part of map (box with coordinates) as raster

Tags: qgis, raster

I would like to export a map of Switzerland (as part of googlemaps) to use as a background for a graph, but I need to know exactly where each corner of the map corresponds to (wrt spatial coordinates). Is there a plugin to do this in QGIS?

Ideally I would like to be able to manually select a bounding box (while using the OpenLayers underneath) and get a picture exported together with the bounding box coordinates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your map has a vector polygon boundary layer you can obtain the node coordinates by running two tools within QGIS:

1. Vector>Geometry Tools>Extract nodes
2. Vector>Geometry Tools>Export/Add geometry columns

This should produce a XCOORD/YCOORD fields within the layer table.

OR

You could create a point layer representing the four cornors of the bounding box, run the Export/Add geometry column tool on it, label the XCOORD/YCOORD fields, null out (100% transparent) the point symbol, and then export your map to raster image.